# calculate near and far value for glPerspective in opengl

Tags: opengl, distance

I need to pass near and far value in glPerspective in opengl code. I am getting all my vertices in eye space by multiplying with ModelViewMatrix in the vertex shader. My problem is that, I need to find the minimum and maximum value out of this, so that I can pass that value to glPerspective. How would I do that? Do I need to calculate them in the vertex shader or in the client space( C code) ?

Comment: You could just make the far value really big. If you want everything to be rendered it will make no difference how large your far distance is as long as it surpasses the maximum distance a vertex will be away from 0, 0, 0

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus , I am already setting such random value for problem. But my problem is very specific. I have to calculate those values based on distance from eye to corners of the mesh. I have use minimum distance as near value and maximum value as far value.

Comment: You could loop through each vertex, use Pythagorean theorem to get the distance of it from 0, 0, 0, and then whichever one comes out as having the largest distance, set your far value to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

near and far are typically not calculated, but just set to reasonable values. 'near' should be close enough that near objects are not clipped, but not so near that all z-buffer precision is gone. 'far' just needs to be far enough away for anything you want to render.

In any event the vertex shader isn't the best place to calculate them, because the matrices get passed in to the shader, so you need to know the values before you get that far.

(it can be viable/useful to calculate near/far dynamically for things like shadows, where you want high-precision - in which case, base it on bounding volumes of the objects you want to render, or some other such approximation).

Comment: Hi JasonD, thanks for the reply. But I have been working on a project where I need to calculate these values depending on distance from eye to corners of mesh. I was able to find some help(http://www.graphicsgroups.com/6-opengl/44e94925d49d72ff.htm) on that, but I couldn't understand it .   My objective is to get distance from the eye to the 4 corners of the mesh then use
the smallest distance from N and the larger distance for F as near and far point in glPerspective.

Comment: plz let me know if you the solution for my problem.

Comment: Whatever you calculate, you have to clamp your near value to something, because you can't have it being at or behind the viewer. If you're guaranteeing that won't happen, you ought to know enough about the scene to set the plane.

Comment: but how would I get the minimum and maximum distance from eye to corners of mesh?

Comment: You don't want the distance, you want the z-value. So you just need to transform the points into camera-space, and use the minimum and maximum z-value.

Comment: agree on that, I am tranforming my points in eye coordinates by multiplying ModelViewMatrix. But how do I get minZ and maxZ value. Sorry about going in detail. I am not that proficient in OpenGL.

Comment: You'll have to do it manually, not with GL. Transform the points and you have your z values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21192/discussion-between-j-modi-and-jasond)

Comment: @JasonD: Actually in most advanced 3D applications the near and far clip plane distances *are* calculated. Before actually rendering the scene a renderer has to go through a preparation phase, in which the required resources are collected, translucent objects sorted and so on. In this phase one can also use the bounding spheres of all the objects to determine the distances for near and far clipping plane. To max out depth buffer resolution this should be done.

Comment: @datenwolf I guess you must work on different applications to me. There are several reasons we don't generally do that. Firstly, because a complex scene will have objects surrounding the camera, meaning that 'near' needs to be clamped anyway - which will be even more true if you use bounding spheres. And also because continually changing the z-buffer creates extremely unpleasant temporal aliasing artefacts at the frame-rates we want. There are times when we'd change it dynamically, but it's usually unnecessary and/or bad.

Comment: @JasonD: I perform the near/far distance estimation in the frustum culling step, which by its nature will consider only objects in the view of the camera. Adjusting the near/far ratio to the scene also should not create unpleasant temporal effects, unless there are constantly objects popping in and out of view; and even with that the slight changes at edges where geometry intersect (there should be no difference in coarse geometry just "sorted" by the depth buffer") should be not noticeable.

Comment: @datenwolf how do you frustum cull before you've defined your frustum? In any case, all I can say is that in my experience your method does not apply to the sorts of situation I deal with. For one then we almost always have objects visible which extend behind the view. If it works for you, great.

Comment: @JasonD: By assuming near=0 and far=∞ you can use them for projection just fine, it just messes up your depth resolution, but for frustum culling you're just interested in if the object is within the fustum, not where exactly.

Comment: @datenwolf I didn't mention projection, but am well aware of how the maths works. Anyway, I think maybe this isn't helping the OP so I'll just leave it there.